# ACCESS_METHODS_DATASET_PARENT SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

Hemos tenido problemas con el timeout en el sistema, la verdad pense que era algo de rendimiento, pero no he logrado sacar el problema ya he hecho y deshecho y ahora me topo con esto, realmente conozco poco, segun lo que lei todos lo que tuvieron un problema con este proceso estaban experimentando los mismos problemas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero hasta aqui he llegado, alguno que tenga una idea

Comment: Hola. Disculpa, podrías elaborar un poco más tu pregunta? No es claro cuál es tu pregunta, qué intentas lograr, qué probaste y qué debería pasar.

Comment: Puedes poner tu configuración de `cost threshold for parallelism` y `max degree of parallelism`? Se encuentran en la vista `sys.configurations`. Cambiar los defaults puede ayudar, pero lo más seguro es que se tengan que ir corrigiendo las consultas más costosas una a una.